# How to undo a DELETE action and respecting RESTful standards?

Tags: api, rest, design-patterns

I'm building a project around my own API, and everything works fine so far, but I'd like to introduce UNDO actions for DELETE.

So far, the DELETE works this way:

```
DELETE /contacts/:id
```

My initial though for UNDO is to call the same DELETE on the same url, which would cancel the deleted state (if this contact is in deleted state), but I don't have any idea if this is a good way or not.

I read [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184532/implementing-the-command-pattern-in-a-restful-api) that looks similar, but the "checkout" part gives the answer something else from what I am looking for.

Is my suggestion good or is there a better way ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have removed a resource using `DELETE` subsequent requests to the resource should return `404 NOT FOUND` or `410 GONE` because **there is no longer a resource there to accept requests.**

If acceptable and you have the state available, the most simple answer is to simply re-create the resource by issuing a `PUT` at the removed resource's URL. Semantically this creates a new resource, replacing any existing state, not really undoing the delete.

Another simple solution is to admit that you're not actually deleting resources and merely change their state in some way to show they're archived. It means you can't use the `DELETE` verb but you can issue `PUT` or `POST` requests to the resource to change between archived and active states.

If you want to preserve `DELETE` as your means of removing the records, then an option is to make it possible to access an archived resource by use of a special `show-archived` value:

```
GET /contacts/<id>?show-archived=true
```

Specifying this on an archived resource would return a `200` on an archived resource instead of one of the `40X` codes. It's a bit mucky, because your resources now have a "superstate" problem of appearing both to exist and not exist depending on how you observe them. It does however mean that you can make a request to the resource to update its state:

```
PUT /contacts/<id>?show-archived=true

State=Active
... all other unchanged fields ...
```

Comment: +1 - another slight variation is a PATCH since you're logically just updating part of the resource (in this case, it's deleted/archived state)

Comment: `PATCH` would be very appropriate to this type of request, however support for it varies; it is quite new to the HTTP verb family.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would make the `UNDO DELETE` a `PUT` over the resource if the `deletion state` is part of the representation, or a `POST` on an `action` if not.

That `action` would look like:

```
POST /contact/id/action/[recover|reactivate] (or whatever you think is more descriptive for the action).
```

But this is just the way I think is most `RESTFul`compliant.

Comment: Apparently, it's agains't RESTFul standards to use verbs in url. Verbs must only be presents in the method